# Custom Annotation Processor creating duplicate classes in Maven

Tags: maven, compilation, annotation-processing

I have a custom annotation processor that generates classes using velocity templates. It works fine but I need to clean the project before building to avoid duplicate classes during compilation.

I even configured velocity to delete the file if already present but it is not helping. Is there something special needed to avoid this?

**Edit**

You can see the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling/src) or check out the code [here](https://javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling).

The NetBeans wrapper pom is [here](https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/simple-marauroa-rcp/src/df31e717097bfbbb3071e887a6e6ea79e088bace/Marauroa-Server-Manager/jWrestling-Wrapper/pom.xml?at=default).

Comment: How to guess? How looks the pom.xml file? Where can we look at the plugin and check?

Comment: Which of the POMS? The wrapped libraries or the NetBeans wrapper?

Comment: Added links to both on the question.

Comment: where are the templates? where is the generation piece of code, the annotation processor configuration?...

Comment: Templates are here: https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling/src/e3497dc1c92d/jWrestling-Server/AnnotationProcessor/src/main/resources?at=default

Comment: Generation code is here: https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling/src/e3497dc1c92d/jWrestling-Server/AnnotationProcessor/src/main/java/games/jwrestling/core/annotation/processor/CardAnnotationProcessor.java?at=default

Comment: Annotation definitions: https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling/src/e3497dc1c92d/jWrestling-Server/AnnotationProcessor/src/main/java/games/jwrestling/core/annotation?at=default

Comment: Where are the classes after generation ? What do you mean by "I need to clean the project before building" ? What are you cleaning ?

Comment: Classes end up in the generated sources folder. The only way to prevent the error is to clean the target folder so the generated classes are no longer there. If I don't I get the error.

Comment: How do you generate the classes ? You run a special command for that ?

Comment: Is a maven plug in. See the maven-processor-plugin configuration here: https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling/src/54b20d6c1bfb7eaacd3cc06b1b16c0a17103a9f3/jWrestling-Server/jWrestling/pom.xml?at=default

Comment: As you don't seem to specify an output directory for your generated sources, I assume they must be generated in target/generated-sources/...
In this case, you should not end up with duplicate classes, unless you copy the generated classes elsewhere, or you have a conflict in classes names. Can you be a bit more specific about the duplicate classes you have ? Where are the classes ? (I mean, the 2 locations in conflict)

Comment: Everything is in the target/generated-sources/ folder. I don't do any fancy copying or anything. Just run the Annotation processor which generates the files there.

Comment: Ok, but as you can hardly have duplicate classes in the same source folder (well, you can, but only if stick to one public class in its own file you can't). So either you have a conflict in classes in, say, target/generated-sources and something else (src/main/java...), or you have an issue at the second generation.... ? What is the mvn command you run ? do you have the problem each time ?

Comment: And you say you have to clean the project before building. You mean mvn clean ? Personnally, I always run mvn clean before building a project (mvn clean ... whatever I want to do) and I don't consider this an issue

Comment: To avoid the duplicate class issue, yes, I have to clean.